# Generate unique device ID without application context or phone permissions

Tags: android

I need to generate a unique device ID in a library class without access to the application context and I can not require any app permissions. The lifecycle of the ID should be the same as the install of the app, it should only change when the app is deleted and re-installed.

How could I generate such an ID?

Comment: You can generate a unique string and save it in the device using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a unique String using

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

And than save it in the device using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).
This string value will be kept in the device until the user uninstall your app.
However, keep in mind that users with a root access can change this value very easily.

Comment: if the user clears cache or data the shared preferences get erased.

Comment: How do I get SharedPreferences without access to the app context?

Comment: You are right. If you don't want it to happen you can write this unique string value in to a file saved in the device. But again, the user can delete this file as well...

Comment: Why don't you want to access the application context? you don't need any special permission for that.